# sigint called multiple times instead of one (C)

Tags: c, fork, sigint

This is a snippet of my code:

```
signal (SIGINT, ( void *)sig_handler); 

while(1){
    newsockd = -1;
    memset(&cli_addr, 0, sizeof(cli_addr));

    if((newsockd = accept(sockd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, (socklen_t *) &socket_len)) < 0){
        perror("Errore nella connessione\n");
        onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Ricevuta richiesta di connessione dall' indirizzo %s\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));

    child_pid = fork();
    if(child_pid < 0){
        perror("Fork error");
        onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
    }
    if(child_pid == 0){
        do_child(newsockd);
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
       while(waitpid(child_pid, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
        continue;
       }
    }
}
```

and the function sig_handler:

```
void sig_handler(const int signo, const int sockd, const int newsockd){
  if (signo == SIGINT){
    printf("Received SIGINT, exiting..\n");
    if(newsockd) close(newsockd);
    if(sockd) close(sockd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}
```

The problem happens when i press "CTRL+C" because sighandler is called multiple times.
Example:

1. Server is listening;
2. 2 x Connection received;
3. 2 x child fork;
4. 2 x child are closed;
5. now i want to close the server so i press CTRL+C;

expected output:
`received SIGINT, exiting....`

**real** output:
`received SIGINT, exiting....`
`received SIGINT, exiting....`
`received SIGINT, exiting....`

Why i got this behaviour?

**EDIT: code updated**
This is what happens when 1 fork is done and when the child has finished i close the server:

```
^C7518
7516
Received SIGINT, exiting...
Received SIGINT, exiting...
```

**SOLUTION FOUND: the problem was that i haven't write `exit(0)` after the instruction `do_child()`...code updated!**

Comment: You're not doing it quite right with `waitpid`, as it will by default block your parent process. Instead call it in a loop while the return value is larger than zero and with the flag `WNOHANG`.

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't check the returned pid, just leave the loop body empty. Remember it's just to clean up after dead child processes, which ones doesn't matter.

Comment: you can print your pid's to see from which process the signal handler is invoked.

Answer (score 4):

The signal is sent to every child process of the current process.
In your code, when you're using `fork`, you create a child process that inherits from the main process the `SIGINT` handler. That's why the message is printed several times.

Comment: but the child process are terminated!

Comment: Are you sure about that ? What does `do_child` ?

Comment: do_child is a complex function that relies on other function! This is a ftp concurrent server :)

Comment: @polslinux Yes but, when a child is closed, you're forking again, aren't you ? (Infinite loop)

Comment: @JulienFouilhé i'm forking if a new connection arrive!

Comment: @polslinux Can you display the current PID with `getpid()` in `sig_handler` ?  

@JoachimPileborg He does that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but i have called `waitpid`, it is on the parent! Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @polslinux I'm sorry I didn't see that at first, removed my comments.

Comment: @JulienFouilhé `^C7518
7516
Received SIGINT, exiting...
Received SIGINT, exiting...`

Comment: @polslinux I thought that you called the exit function in your function do_child... To exit properly, I would suggest to unstack till the main function... :)

Comment: What do you mean by "unstack till the main function" ?? :)

Comment: I mean instead of using `exit()`, you would return to the main function using the keyword `return` depending on **return values of functions called**, and use `return(EXIT_SUCCESS)` again in the `main()` function :) It's proper and nobody asks himself why return values aren't verified. But it's just an advice and things I'm just trying to apply (sometimes I don't).

Answer (score 2):

There are few observations,

1)You should better use sigaction instead of signal function.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigaction.html

2)Now some fixes in your current code. You may use

```
if(child_pid == 0)
{
   /*Now in the child make again the action for SIGINT default, so that 
   your handler does not get called.*/ 
       signal (SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
       do_child(newsockd);
}
```

3)Why you are calling waitpid in the main loop? You should have a handler for SIGCHLD and then use wait/waitpid inside it.

Ideally after creating a child to serve client, the main loop should go back to accept.
(If it is geeting blocked after creation of a child then how your server becomes a concurrent server?)

(Or for the first version, I would suggest you avoid this instead use, after  your call to signal handler for SIGINT,

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);  //This should  automatically get rid of zombies.
```

(Pl. experiment this in your system)

Link for reference - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD

4)It seems your argument to the handler for SIGINT is also not proper.The proper prototype is

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

But your handler is

```
void sig_handler(const int signo, const int sockd, const int newsockd).
```

How the values of sockfd & newsockfd are getting passed?
Link

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/signal.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you kill the child process.If the child process is not in Zomb status yet, your sign_handler will work on it. May need add more log to clarify the sequence of child process life cycles.

Comment: `^C7518
7516
Received SIGINT, exiting...
Received SIGINT, exiting...`

Comment: I mean what the child process status after "2 x child are closed". Are we sure it is killed and go into Zomb status?

Comment: I think when you start ctl + c, we need know how many child you have created and how many you have closed in the log. wish this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note: I found that I was getting multiple SIGINT for a single CTRL+C as well.  When I checked my task manager, I actually had multiple hung node.js scripts for this application.  Once I terminated them in task manager, I started receiving single SIGINT as expected.